# ArcToolbox model run but warning output in Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I have created an ArcToolbox and a Model in the toolbox. It uses a lot of Spatial Analyst tools and deals with raster images.

When I imported the toolbox in a Python script and ran the model from Python in Windows command prompt, I got a few warning messages as below but the model got run successfully.

```
<string>:1: SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level
```

It was shown several times. I am unable to tell where this error comes from.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you specify your problem a little bit more, e.g. by providing the script you are using to import toolbox and model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your warning message sounds similar to this [ArcGIS Discussion Forum thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/44682-Raster-Calculator-Python) and the solution there seemed to be:

> according to the help, the raster calculator is for use inside arcmap
>   only, for calculations in python you should use mapalgebra:
>   http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm

Perhaps you are trying to use the Raster Calculator rather than Map Algebra in the Python code you are calling from outside ArcMap.

Comment: Yeah. I used Raster Calculator in the Model but not Python script. Then I made a Python script, imported the toolbox and called the Model from there. So it is not directly calling Raster Calculator from Python script. From the command prompt window, I could see it ran successfully with a few SyntaxWarning messages.